# ServiceStack - Katana and OWIN

Tags: .net, web-services, web-applications, owin, katana

I basically want to run multiple application running on one httplistener. How can I configure katana using owin with servicestack. Furthermore does anyone know how I can integrate this with an existing web api, MVC app.

I want to handle all my authentication in  console application using katana, then host multiple web application on it. ServiceStack console application, existing web api application, existing ASP.NET MVC3 application and I also want to put SignalR in it. All on same httplistner, then either forward my requests accordingly depending on the URL.

Could anyone show me how to do this? If there is a better way then Katana. Please point me in right direction.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to host multiple service stack services, you'll have to put them in their own App Domain.

Comment: Is there no way I can just control 1 service stack app http://mydomain/ServicestackApp1

Comment: mydomain.com/ServiceStackApp2. mydomain.com/servicestackapp2 but run all of these though one httplistner hosted in katana

Comment: mydomain.com/webapi. Then let all my authentication run through katana and owin

Comment: Service stack Service hosts are tied to a single Uri.  One per app-domain.

Comment: What i'm looking to is set up 1 service that handles http requests and authentication for multiple different service. E.g mydomain/webapi, mydomain/servicestack then takes the requests and forwards them to the appropriate http handlers. Is there any way you can do this. I was thinking katana could be a good solution for doing this. You have any suggestions?

Comment: This is what owin is for - composing webapplications behind a server - but service stack 3.x doesn't support owin. It is unknown if it will be supported in 4.x

Comment: Note on ServiceStack 4+ - It is no longer free except for OpenSource projects. You might want to move to a full Katana/WebAPI Self-Host.